# Java class object assigned values are available in other thread while I don't want so

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a class annotated with @component, which has an attribute `listOfAccounts`, defined like this in class definition –

```
@Component
public class UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService {

..
..
List<BulkAccountUpdateDetails> listOfAccounts = new ArrayList<BulkAccountUpdateDetails>();
..
..
```

The attribute `listOfAccounts` is initiated inside a method `processUuidsCommon()` like this as well –

```
listOfAccounts = new ArrayList<BulkAccountUpdateDetails>();
```

This method is being called by multi threading logic -

```
class BucketProcessThread extends Thread {
        private final UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService;

        public void run() {
            ..
            ..
            usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService.processUuidsCommon();

            ..
        }
}
```

It is used by multiple threads. Problem is that values initiated by one thread are available by other thread, whereas I expect them to be reset.

**Update**

I have added following logging -

From the run method of BucketProcessThread class -

```
            logger.info("Picking bucket counter {}, named {} inside thread {} ",bucketCounter, redisBucketName, startingRedisBucketNumber);
```

From UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService class -

```
logger.info("Total in listOfAccounts post {} in {} bucket, first value {} ",listOfAccounts.size(),redisKeyName,listOfAccounts.get(0).getUuid());
```

Here are the values printed from the 2 threads showing the same value set  -

1st thread -

```
2019-04-29 15:47:01,179 74253 [pool-6-thread-1] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.BucketProcessThread [BankManager.java:2287] - Picking bucket counter 0, named predeactivate7DaysNoKycUuids_0 inside thread 0 
..
..
2019-04-29 15:47:02,703 75777 [pool-6-thread-1] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.w.UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService [UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService.java:151] - Total in listOfAccounts post 184 in predeactivate7DaysNoKycUuids_0 bucket, first value 8911542905142650081
```

And 2nd thread -

```
2019-04-29 15:47:01,285 74359 [pool-6-thread-2] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.BucketProcessThread [BankManager.java:2287] - Picking bucket counter 5, named predeactivate7DaysNoKycUuids_5 inside thread 5 
..
..
..
2019-04-29 15:47:02,942 76016 [pool-6-thread-2] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.w.UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService [UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService.java:151] - Total in listOfAccounts post 199 in predeactivate7DaysNoKycUuids_5 bucket, first value 8911542905142650081
```

This shows that the two threads are picking two separate redis buckets. Just to confirm, I have confirmed the values in those redis buckets. Values of either of the buckets (depending on which bucket is picked by a thread) is assigned to the variable in both the threads.

**Update 2**

Instantiation of usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService in BucketProcessThread -

```
public BucketProcessThread(usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService
            ) {

        this.usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService = usersBucketForExpiryUtilityService;
    }
```

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain? Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Try adding `@Scope("prototype")` to your component.

Comment: @Arnaud tried this as well. Same behavior.

Comment: could you pls add details about how `BucketProcessThread` is being used in the application and how you're instantiating `UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService` in `BucketProcessThread`

Comment: @Sindbad90 added in update 2. Found the reason - due to autowiring, same instance of UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService  class is being used. Since variable is defined at class level, it is overlapping. Now, I have removed the class level variable assignment from inside UsersBucketForExpiryUtilityService   and returning from individual methods.

Comment: Exactly my doubt - using protoype bean in a singleton via autowiring. Glad you resolved it.

Comment: @Sindbad90 I see no difference with or without @Scope("prototype"). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere in your code, a `protoype` bean is autowired in a `singleton` bean. Can you confirm that?